# How to take input from .in file and provide output in another .txt file using Netbeans for java programs?

Tags: java, file, netbeans, input, output

I am looking from Google CodeJam point of view.
I have written my code which takes the input like

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s = br.readLine();
```

Now, the contest provides the input in form of .in files and asks to upload the output file.
How exactly do we take the input from the .in file and output the solution to another .txt file?

I'm a newbie. Please help and pardon for any mistakes in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 files,
One -the input File: **in.txt**
Another -the ouput File: **out.txt**
Then while executing your code, Simply execute from command prompt as

**java test < *in.txt* > *out.txt***

(Replace your desired input and output file names in place of in.txt and out.txt respectively)
This will take input from the content you have placed in in.txt,
and Place the output in out.txt.

Also you are generally asked to upload the code file, not the output file.
(Just check instructions once again. I amy be wrong too.)

Comment: The question is pretty specific and straightforward. I want to achieve this using Netbeans.

Comment: You're correct! However, google code jam asks for both output and source code. During practise, they only ask for output though.

Comment: @kaushal-shah you can use file reader and file output for that but this is the better way